# Defining a function for the construction of a bordered hessian

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, mathematical-optimization

I think in Mathematica the omission of a function that can create a bordered matrix. This code works

```
m = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
k = {α, β}
l1 = Insert[ k, 0, 1];
c1 = Insert[Transpose[m], k, 1] // Transpose;
m1 = Insert[c1, l1, 1];
m1 // MatrixForm
```

and gives

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \alpha  & \beta\\
\alpha & a & b\\
\beta & c  & d
\end{pmatrix}$

as expected.

So I have tried to design a function. But obviously it doesn't work

```
bordhess[mat_?MatrixQ[mat], vec_?VecQ[vec] ] := 
 Block[{x = mat, y = vec},
  l1 = Insert[ y, 0, 1];
  c1 = Insert[Transpose[x], k, 1] // Transpose;
  Insert[c1, l1, 1]
  ]
```

and even If I have been able to create such a function, I wonder how to generalize the problem to many vectors.

Comment: `ArrayFlatten[{{0, {k}}, {Transpose@{k}, m}}]`

Comment: Thanks too much simple for my complicated mind!

Comment: @SimonRochester You should make this an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also,

```
borderF = ArrayReshape[{0, #, Transpose[{##}]}, 1 + Dimensions@#2] &;

mat = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {4, 4}];
multipliers = Array[Subscript[λ, #] &, 4];
borderF[multipliers, mat] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Does this do the multi-row block-bordering shown in the last images of Simon's and my answers? I believe that's what the OP is asking about (when wondering "how to generalize the problem to many vectors"), but I could be wrong.

Comment: @MichaelE2, no it doesn't handle multi-row borders. Still trying to figure out the appropriate argument for `ArrayReshape` to get multi-row borders.

Comment: @cyrcyrille.piatecki , i suppose the `Accept` is a mistake:) considering the  generality and elegance of Simon's and Michal's answers.

Comment: Of course, I have checked yours as I could have checked an other because all were satisfying I should have checked the more elegant but I do not know <hich is the one. Perhaps we could ask for the possibility to  multi check some time.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with `ArrayFlatten`. Here is a generalization to one or more vectors -- I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for:

```
bordhess[mat_?MatrixQ, mat1_?MatrixQ] := ArrayFlatten[{{0, mat1}, {Transpose@mat1, mat}}]

bordhess[mat_?MatrixQ, vec_?VectorQ] := bordhess[mat, {vec}]
```

Then you have

```
m = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
k = {α, β};
j = {γ, δ};

bordhess[m, k] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
bordhess[m, {k, j}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer to the title question, about constructing a bordered Hessian, in case someone come looking for answer to it. It comes directly from calculus, instead of playing with matrices.

Basically thus:

```
D[f + λ.g, {{λ1, λ2,..., x1, x2,...}, 2}]
```

where

```
λ = {λ1, λ2,...}
```

are the Lagrange multipliers and

```
x = {x1, x2,...}
```

are the variables of `f` and `g`.

Example:

```
ClearAll[bH];
bH[f_, g_List, x_List, param_: K] := bH[f, g, x, Array[param, Length@g]];
bH[f_, g_List, x_List, λ_List] := D[f + λ.g, {Join[λ, x], 2}];

bH[w^4 x + x^3 y + y^2 z + z^4,
 {w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2, w^2 + 2 x^2 + 3 y^2 + 4 z^2},
 {w, x, y, z}, {λ, μ}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Bordered Hessian can also be used in checking quasi-concavity

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki Yes, second derivatives are useful. (I'm not sure why the comment, actually. I suppose you mean specializing at `bH[f, {f}, {x, y,..}, {λ}] /. λ -> 0`.)

Comment: Michael E2 Not exactly. In economics, one is obliged to assume that  every upper level set of the consumer's ordering is convex, which is equivalent to the condition that any function that represents the consumer's ordering is quasiconcave (for definition see http://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/qcc/t). If the function is $C^2$ the condition of quasiconcavity is linked to the bordered hessian

Comment: -> continued --- principal minors should be alternatively negative/ positive beginning with the second order --- by construction the first order is 0. If the function is strtictly quasi-convex then on has a maximum.

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki It seems the same thing, no? At least the formula for bordered Hessian in the ref. link in your comment is the same.

Comment: I must aknowledge they are the same.